# Tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with pandas dataframe.

The dataframe (nammed `data_table`) is:

```
    rec               age  income student credit_rating buys_computer
0    r1       less_thirty    high      no          fair            no
1    r2       less_thirty    high      no     excellent            no
2    r3  thirtyone_fourty    high      no          fair           yes
3    r4    greater_fourty  medium      no          fair           yes
4    r5    greater_fourty     low     yes          fair           yes
5    r6    greater_fourty     low     yes     excellent            no
6    r7  thirtyone_fourty     low     yes     excellent           yes
7    r8       less_thirty  medium      no          fair            no
8    r9       less_thirty     low     yes          fair           yes
9   r10    greater_fourty  medium     yes          fair           yes
10  r11       less_thirty  medium     yes     excellent           yes
11  r12  thirtyone_fourty  medium      no     excellent           yes
12  r13  thirtyone_fourty    high      no          fair           yes
13  r14    greater_fourty  medium      no     excellent            no
```

**Now I need to determine the probability of picking** `buys_computer='yes'` **with** `age='less_thirty'`.

My `code`:

```
data_table = pd.read_csv('DT.csv')
total_elements = len(data_table.index)
count = 0
for row in data_table.iterrows():
    if row['age'] == 'less_thirty' and row['buys_computer'] == 'yes':
        count += 1
    probability = count/total_elements
    print(probability)
```

But it gives error like:

```
---> 42         if row['age'] == 'less_thirty' and row['buys_computer'] == 'yes':

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterrows` yields a tuple of index and row, you would need to do:

```
count = 0
for _, row in data_table.iterrows():
    if row['age'] == 'less_thirty' and row['buys_computer'] == 'yes':
        count += 1
probability = count/len(data_table)
print(probability)
```

But it's more efficient to go vectorial:

```
count = (data_table['age'].eq('less_thirty')
       & data_table['buys_computer'].eq('yes')).sum()
print(count/len(data_table))
```

output: `0.14285714285714285`

Answer (score 1):

Because iterrows returns a tuple, so you cannot directly use a conditional statement without unpacking. That said, why loop when you can make the comparison directly using:

```
condition = df[(df['age'] == 'less_thirsty') & (df['buys_computer'] == 'yes')]
print(len(condition)/ len(df))
```

in which df = your original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate probability and print it outside the for loop.